# MySQLi Prepared Statement Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm writing what I think is a fairly basic prepared statment using `MySQLi`. Statement follows (in which `$connection` is the `MySQLi` instance):

```
    $venue = $_POST['venue'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
       $query = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO events (date, time, showTime, venue, description) VALUES ('$date', '$time', '$showtime', '?', '?')");
       $query->bind_param('ss', $venue, $description);
    }
    elseif (isset($_POST['edit'])) {
       $query = $connection->prepare("UPDATE events SET date = '$date', time = '$time', showTime = '$showtime', venue = '?', description = '?' WHERE id ='$id'");
       $query->bind_param('ss', $venue, $description);
    }

    $query->execute();
```

This fails with the following in the `log: Number of variables doesn't match the number of parameters in a prepared statement`.

I'm not a genius at math, but there are two placeholders in the statement and two variables in the `bind_param` :) I've also confirmed that the types are correct: if I `var_dump $venue` and `$description`, I get `strings`. Can someone help me see where my mistake is?

Thanks!

Comment: why are you preparing statements but also interpolating strings?  That's likely to open you to sql injection vulnerabilities.  In both `prepare()`s, you have 2 question marks but provide 3 bind parameters.  Could be wrong, but don't think bound parameters' question mark placholders ever need to be quoted.   Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going into much details, please do not mix 'direct values' with value holders (?) in your query. Instead, bind them all at once. Try the following:

```
$query = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO events (date, time, showTime, venue, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$query->bind_param('sssss', $date, $time, $showtime, $venue, $description);
```